# How do I calculate the sharpe ratio of a portfolio of stocks?

Tags: sharpe-ratio, log-returns

If I have daily prices for $N$ stocks, how do I calculate the Sharpe ratio for an equal volatility weight portfolio?

On each day, I have calculated log returns as:
$$
r_{t}^{s} = \ln{price_{t}\over{price_{t-1}}}
$$

I have then measured the standard deviation of each this series in a 60-day window, and normalised this so each series has approximate deviation of 1.

**Question 1:**

Is the portfolio daily return equal to the arithmetic mean of the individual stocks $s$, assuming I will allocate on a equal volatility basis before trading:

$$
\text{Portfolio Log Return}_t = \frac{1}{N} \sum_s r_t^s
$$

**Question 2:**

If I take the portfolio return from above, and use these figures to create a Sharpe ratio

$$
\text{Sharpe ratio} = \frac{\sqrt(252)*\text{Arithmetic Average of LogReturns}}{\text{Std Deviation of LogReturns}}
$$

- Does this make any sense?
- What's the relationship of a Sharpe ratio calculated in this way to the Sharpe ratios published in journals and fund brochures?
- Can a Sharpe calculated in this way be converted back to 'realized returns'?

I have calculated this value for a period 1993-1997 for the 500 most traded stocks, weighted an equal volatility basis, and got a value of approximately 7, which is definitely not right.

Comment: The return on a portfolio (assuming certain weights and a certain rebalancing policy) is generally **not equal** to the mean of daily returns. What are your weights and what is you rebalancing frequency (weekly, monthly, quarterly, ...)? What do you mean by equal volatility?

Comment: I'm rebalancing daily, based a 60 day moving average of the volatility of log returns, such that balancing factor would lead to standard deviation of log-returns of 1 for every stock.

Comment: Daily rebalancing (with no transaction costs taken into account) generally leads to overestimates of rates of return because of microstructure effect such as bid-ask bounce. In real life such rates of return are generally not achievable.